# Storing an enum property inside CoreData and making it convenient

Tags: ios, core-data, enums, typedef, nsnumber

One of my model object has an enum property. To store it in CoreData, I've used an NSNumber object.

Nevertheless, I'd like to access it as an enum type in a convenient way. What is the best practice to achieve that?

So far, I've gone with the following code.

in MyObject.h

```
typedef enum _ABType {
    ABTypeUnknown,
    ABTypeValue1,
    ...
    ABTypeValueN
} ABType;

@interface MyObject : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * myPersistentEnum; // Defined in my Core Data model

@property (nonatomic) ABType myConvenientEnum;
```

in MyObject.m

```
@dynamic myPersistentEnum;

- (BOOL)isValidEnumValue {
    if (self.myPersistentEnum) {
        int intValue = [self.type intValue];
        if (intValue >= ABTypeValue1 && intValue <= ABTypeValueN) {
            return YES;
        }        
    }

    ELog(@"Undefined enumValue %@", self.myPersistentEnum);
    return NO;
}

- (ABType)myConvenientEnum {
    if ([self isValidEnumValue]) {
        return [self.type intValue];
    }

    return ABTypeUnknown;
}

- (void)setMyConvenientEnum:(ABType)enumValue {
    NSNumber *oldValue = [self.myPersistentEnum retain];
    self.myPersistentEnum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:enumValue];
    if ([self isValidEnumValue]) {
        [oldValue release];
    } else {
        self.myPersistentEnum = oldValue;
        [oldValue release];
    }
}
```

My questions are:

- Is there something wrong in the code above?
- Is `int` the right type to use when converting an enum to NSNumber? (NSNumber doesn't provide an `-(enum)enumValue;` method)
- Would you leave the validation aspect to the runtime CoreData model validation?
- [NEW] How can I make clear for other developers that the convenient property should be used and not the NSNumber property?

Answer (score 0):

CoreData in iOS 5 supports native integer types, so you can use that instead of NSNumber if you want.

**EDIT**

FWIW, the compiler can make enum be as small as necessary for the possible values it holds.  It is best to cast the enum -- (int)myEnumValue -- when assigning into a NSNumber, because it assumes the type is the exact size you tell it.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know this. Unfortunately, the apps I'm working on have to support iOS 4, at least for another couple of months.